# Can't Decrement var in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in Javascript and am building a dynamic webform.
My table works fine in renaming new rows (adding a new name with "index"), but it doesn't work when I remove rows and create new ones, because my "index--;" doesn't work.
Notice that when i say table is just a way of speaking...
What is wrong with my code?

Snippet

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
            var index = 0; // 
    
    
        $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
            var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
            $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
                index++;
                $novaLinha = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true)
                $novaLinha.appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
                $novaLinha.find('label').attr('class', 'hideMobile').end();
                $novaLinha.find('[id="itemLinha"]').attr('class', 'row top-buffer-novoItem col-md-12 control-group' + index).end();
                $novaLinha.find('[name="insumo"]').attr('name', 'insumo ' + index).end();
                $novaLinha.find('[name="detalhe"]').attr('name', 'detalhe ' + index).end();
                $novaLinha.find('[name="quantidade"]').attr('name', 'quantidade ' + index).end();
                $novaLinha.find('[name="unidade"]').attr('name', 'unidade ' + index).end();
            });
            $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
                if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)  {    // Quando se apaga a primeira linha quando há mais de uma, não aparece o título da tabela no desktop          
                    index--;
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent('.multi-field').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    
    };
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
        <div class="row top-buffer-inicio " >
            <div class="multi-fields col-md-12">
                <div class="multi-field">
                    <div class = "row top-buffer-novoItem col-md-12 control-group" id="itemLinha">
                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="insumo">INSUMO</label>                                                    
                            <div data-name="insumo">
                                <input type="text" name='insumo'  placeholder='Ex. Bloco de Concreto' class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                            <label for="detalhe"> DETALHE </label> 
                            <div class = "" data-name="detalhe">
                                <input type="text" name='detalhe' placeholder='Ex. Estrutural 14x19x39' class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                            <label for="quantidade"> QTD </label>
                            <div class = "" data-name="quantidade">
                                <input type="text" name='quantidade' placeholder="Ex. 55" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label for="unidade"> UNIDADE </label>
                            <div class = "" data-name="unidade">                             
                                <input type="text" name='unidade'  placeholder='Ex. Unitário' class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 ">
                            <label > </label>    
                            <div class = "remove-field ">                                                                           
                                <div name="remove" class='pull-right btn btn-danger btn-block glyphicon glyphicon-remove '></div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                                        
        <div class="row top-buffer-novoItem">
            <div class="col-md-12">                                          
                <div class="col-md-2 pull-right form-group">
                    <div id="add_row" class="add-field btn btn-grey pull-right">Novo Item</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `I am new in Javascript and am building a dynamic webform` - try to build NOT dynamic first, `// Quando se apaga a primeira` - what is it?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Why don't you try to narrow it down to see what's causing the problem?

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ In what way?

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db0th4Lq/1/) it is working

Comment: FYI: All those .end() calls are a waste.

Comment: It is just a comment for a future implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is you are expecting the click event that is registered before a dynamic element is created to be called. Click events do not magically get hooked up to the element after the element is created. You either need to bind the events every time you create an element or you need to use event delegation.

Change

```
$('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
```

to

```
$($wrapper).on("click", '.multi-field .remove-field', function() {
```

Comment: How come it works anyway in Chrome? Timing issue? http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3s4L68dv/

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3s4L68dv/) even though you should delegate the click as posted by *epascarello*

To have a better counter, simply use the length of the added multifields:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/g1edkf6t/)

```
$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
   var index = $('.multi-fields .multi-field').length;
```

Even better: Since you do not use the index for anything except name, instead, assuming your back end is PHP, do this - add [] to all input fields in the template:

```
<input type="text" name='detalhe[]'
```

Since you remove any field where removed is clicked, with your current code you can actually create the same name by adding 3, removing the middle one and adding one more.

Comment: Downvoters comment or your downvote is completely useless to everybody

Comment: Looks to be because the scoping of `index` is fine.  Everything is within the `ready` callback.

Comment: I found nothing related to scope

Comment: Your downvotes are probably because your answer does not mention why the `index--` is not firing...

Comment: $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
  var index = $novaLinha.find("'.multi-field").length;

That's a much more clevared solution. It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you do not seem to use index for anything except creating a new name? Am I correct? If so, no need for it at all in for example php. Give a name ending in `[]` and you can use an array on the server